# WIX Project - Auto blogger with python and API?

Tags: python, blogs, velo

I'm trying to create a way to "auto post" blog posts which include an image to a particular section of my WIX hosted blog /blog/categories/news. I have created an API which has all privilege's however, I cant see to be able to get the right python code to play right. My idea is to have a cron job run a python script once a day, which would post to my site. Would be extremely grateful to collaborate with someone to pass ideas / code snippets back and forth as this has been something I have not been able to figure out on my own, very new to this.

Thank you in advance -

I have tried something like below and it just did not work out. Not sure if I am on the right track or not.

```
import requests

def post_to_wix(api_key, content):
    url = 'https://www.your-wix-site.com/_functions/myEndpoint'  # Replace with your specific Wix endpoint

    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_key}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    data = {
        'content': content  # This structure depends on your Wix API requirements
    }

    response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('Content posted successfully')
    else:
        print('Failed to post content')
        print('Status Code:', response.status_code)
        print('Response:', response.text)

# Example usage
api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'  # Replace with your actual API key
content = 'Hello, this is a test post!'  # Replace with your actual content
post_to_wix(api_key, content)
```